# Differential amplifier with current mirror

Tags: amplifier

I am having difficulties with sections e and g and would appreciate some assistance/guidance if possible.

As for section e, I figured I could use the following expression for the current to evaluate  \$V_{sd4}\$:

\$I_{sd4}=k_4(V_{gs4}+0.2)^2(1+0.05V_{sd4})\$, where \$I_{sd4}=23.745 \mu A\$ and was found in previous sections. The problem is that this yields \$V_{sd4}=0V\$ and \$V_{01_{dc}}=5V\$, which doesn't seem correct.

As for section g, I believe there's an error here, isn't there? How is \$r_{o6}\$ even relevant to the DC calculation asked for??
[image]

Comment: *How is \$r_{o6}\$ even relevant to the DC calculation asked for??* **Who says that it is ?** \$r_{o6}\$ is a small signal parameter. You first determine the DC operating point of the circuit, then you determine the value of the small signal parameters. Sometimes the \$r_{ds}\$ does slightly influence the DC operating point. That seems to be the point of the exercise. Stop assuming questions are "wrong" when you do not see where they're going/make sense. Because often those are the questions that are testing you if you **understand** the problem.

Comment: @FakeMoustache often in this course there are errors in the exercises given to us! This has been affirmed many times by the professor. Ergo there was indeed room to suspect there was one yet again. Say I initially found \$r_{06}\$ to be \$0.42114M \Omega\$. The relation between \$r_o\$ and \$I_{ds}\$ is \$r_{o}=|V_A/I_{ds}|\$. Could I simply write \$|I_{ds}|=20/r_{06}\$, as \$V_A=20\$ and substitute the value I first found for \$r_{o6}\$?

Comment: How did you calculate the IREF=IR1?If we have this data we can find the solution

Comment: @elecV1 \$I_{ref}=0.5 \cdot 120 \cdot 300(V_{d5}-0.2)^2\$, which yielded \$I_{ref}=47.49 \mu A\$

Comment: *to be 0.42114MΩ* **Real** engineers round that off to 421 kohm, no need to be that precise, everything varies over temperature anyway. If you calculated that r0 to be 421 kohm that simply means there's a 421 kohm in parallel with the Drain-Source of that transistor in the **small signal model**.

Comment: d)gm1 = sqrt{2*kn'*(W/L)*ID1}

Comment: @FakeMoustache there's hardly a need to be rude. We were instructed to use about 5 decimal places. I am well aware that this is simply the value of the resistor in parallel with DS6. However, I am asked for the *DC* current through that MOS. How am I connecting the two other than by using the expression I suggested above?

Comment: @elecV1 I am not sure I understand how to use that to find the DC current through M6. I have found \$gm_1=19.6m mho\$

Comment: *We were instructed to use about 5 decimal places* I was not rude, I just explained common practice. Then next time ask **why** 5 decimal places is needed. By asking for 5 decimal places the teacher does not prepare **you** for the real world where many things in EE are only about 1% accurate. The Ids formula already takes channel modulation into account, the r0 is a small signal parameter, so it does not influence the DC solution since it's effect is already taken into account by lambda.

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't fully understand how ID6 varies wrt ro6. Given that r06 isn't neglected as indicated, how does that affect the value of ID6 which I found earlier (IREF)?